# Compatibility research on GPU soldering

Tags: motherboard, gpu, soldering

So am seeking any generalized way to know if a dedicated GPU could be soldered if a motherboard had an integrated place to put it, in this case, in an "Acer Aspire A515-55"
[GPU dedicated space on motherboard in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/337Z5.jpg)

As you can see, it has a GPU space to fill and 2 VRAMS for it.

I know it would be hard to know if the motherboard have enough power for the GPU to actually work without a full diagram of it, but that's not my question. I want to know what kind of knowledge should I learn to help me in this situation and to know the compatibilities issues this could have (And for this let's assume there aren't any issues in soldering) in short words, I want to know everything about it, so if anyone have any reference i could read to know more about these kind of topics, I would be grateful c:

Anyway if someone wants to give help in the specified case of the Acer notebook, it would be nice too.

BTW if there's any bad orthography or grammar errors in this, sorry, am not a native english speaker, but I'm trying my best lol

Comment: I think if you knew about surface mount flow soldering, you probably would not be asking here.

Comment: What're you trying to do - practically? There's probably options for getting *a* GPU working that would not involve essentially board level soldering with specialised tools. Stuff like using a break out board on your wireless adaptor slot might be less of a headache

Comment: There is no way to solder a non-mobile GPU onto a motherboard that doesn’t already have a GPU soldered. It wouldn’t just be any mobile GPU, it would have to be the same generation, and exactly the same specifications except perhaps the model name. What you are talking about it unrealistic. You want to know everything about a subject that people spend their entire careers learning how to do properly (soldering BGA ICs).

Comment: This is a $600 laptop there is no way the battery or motherboard will handle the power load of anything modern, nor does it have enough heat sink capacity. The time,money, and effort involved will likely cost 10+ times a new laptop.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be more annoying and difficult than just replacing the motherboard or laptop.  If you absolutely have to go down this path then you should get a professional who might have access to the circuit diagrams and components required to do it for you. It is non-trivial and could take days or weeks to do properly.

Firstly, only certain GPU chips will fit on that area so you will have to research what models of GPU the laptop supports to find what chips would fit, then you'll have to source a supplier for the potentially very specific model you need as they may have different packages with different numbers of pins, then you'll need to find out the specific memory chips you need as again there are different chips with different pinouts.

You'll then need to learn how to do BGA soldering and spend the money on a BGA rework station and for a beginner there is a chance you'll completely destroy something or blow other components off of the board area. You'll need to figure out what all the other components that need to go on these areas:

[image: these areas]

They will be all the various resistors, capacitors, inductors and other power chips around the GPU that it needs to work in the first place. Without them you can fit the memory and GPU but they'll have no power, configuration or connection to the rest of the board.

This is not work for the faint of heart or even hobbyists.

Comment: Also - even if its a common motherboard - I suspect firmware might differ, or even cut traces between models. Assuming you could even get a loose or pulled GPU

Comment: And don't forget you will also have to devise a custom cooling solution that will fit the case.